# HighChart son data is not displaying on webpage

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

Due to having been able to get a working sample chart on the same page, I suspect that the reason the desired chart not displaying is due to how the data is being loaded (or not loaded).

My data is time series data and is kept in `./json/chartData.json`:

```
[
  {
    "2015-01-08": "35"
  },
  {
    "2015-01-09": "35"
  },
  {
    "2015-01-10": "35"
  }
]
```

The page attempting to display the data is `template.html` and contains the following javascript which I strongly suspect is incorrect somewhere.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

            var processed_json = new Array();   
            $.getJSON('json/chartData.json', function(data) {

                // Populate series
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    processed_json.push([data[i].key, parseInt(data[i].value)]);
                }

                // draw chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                plotOptions: { 
                  series: { 
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    animation: false 
                  }
                },  
                chart: {
                    type: "spline"
                },
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                xAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: "Date"
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: "Number of tickets"
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    data: processed_json
                }]
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

A container in the body of `template.html` allows the page to render the chart:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 700px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Note that once the page is rendered I'm then using `wkhtmltopdf` to output the page to pdf format. I added the plot options section in order to allow `wkhtmltopdf` to render this correctly.

```
            plotOptions: { 
              series: { 
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                shadow: false,
                animation: false 
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

My json was formatted incorrectly. It should have been:

```
[
  {
    "key": "2015-01-08",
    "value": "35"
  },
  {
    "key": "2015-01-09",
    "value": "35"
  },
  {
    "key": "2015-01-10",
    "value": "35"
  }
]
```